# How to Add Subdomain SPF Record on every subdomain (single attempt)?

Tags: dns, spf

Kindly Help, I want to add SPF record on each and every subdomains ( xyz.example.com , abc.example.com etc ) .

I need to put an SPF on every possible subdomain? is there any way to put SPF Record on every subdomain through single attempt ?

It looks like we need to have this SPF record on every single subdomain, which is an annoyance..

Would be much appreciated.

Comment: So how are you going to add these to the DNS Server? With PHP?

Comment: You might find this useful https://serverfault.com/questions/322949/do-spf-records-for-primary-domain-apply-to-subdomains

Comment: Thanks alot for the comment ..